Windows won't boot anymore after failed attempt to clone the drive
I have a laptop with Windows 7 (yeah I know it's not supported/secure anymore but I only use it offline with specialized software that doesn't work as well in newer OS).
Anyway I wanted to move this OS which is still on a HDD to a SSD drive, I downloaded DiskGenius and started the "clone image" option sending the image to an external USB SSD drive I have. Thing is DiskMGenius just hanged and crashed my whole system, I couldn't do anything so I just decided to unplug the laptop from the power plug (I know this is a bad idea in general but again it was completely stuck).
Now it won't boot, it gets to the screen with Windows logo where it should load the OS but it seemingly load the OS forever, it's stuck.
I tried pressing F8 right at the beginning but for some reason it doesn't get into recovery/safe mode, nothing happens.
Downloaded Rescatux on a USB drive, started Gparted in it and it nominally reads the Windows partition but with an exclamation sign, also it reads the dimension of the disk but not the amount of occupied/free space within it, it says "unable to read the contents of the filesystem". The partition is NTSF btw. Did I just scramble the hard disk by abruptly plugging it off from electricity? Anything that I can do to ascertain whether the filesystem is fixable or not?

Yes, likely the file system is damaged. Best might be to save what daata you can by booting from another OS, e.g., WinPE or RE (as from Hiren's BoottCD) or Linux, and then reinstall Win7 : https://techpp.com/2018/04/16/windows-7-iso-official-direct-download-links/

Was the cloning process that messed up the filesystem or was the fact that I abruptly cut the power (this has happened many times and never damaged my laptop). I read that many users experience the bcd getting messed up after a disk cloning, why don't they warn you that this might happen? Meh.                                           I would rather attempt to fix the filesystem if it's at all possible before reinstalling

Btw I ran a diagnostic tool and it says that Windows cannot boot because "winload.efi" is missing, this seems to indicate the bcd got messed up
